The natural maps $H^k(X,\mathbb{C})\to H^k(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ and $H^k(X,\mathbb{C})\to H^{0,k}(X)$ coincide. (Lemma 3.3.1 Huybrechts)
The proof makes use of this diagram.

Using it, one can describe $H^k(X,\mathbb{C})\to H^k(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$  induced by the inclusion $\mathbb{C}\subset \mathcal{O}_X$ in terms of explicit representatives as follows:
For a class $[a]\in H^k(X,\mathbb{C})$  we choose its harmonic representative $a\in \mathcal{H}^k(X)$ Its image is represented by the $(0, k)$-
part of it, which is again harmonic.  Of course, this describes nothing but the
projection given by the bidegree decomposition.

I am confused about the proof, does the above prove $H^k(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\cong H^{0,k}(X)$ ?  Could someone provide a brief explanation of how the argument in the lemma establishes this claim?
Does the above resolutions yield this diagram ?

So the map $H^k(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to H^{0,k}(X)$ is as isomorphism ?
I don't see how we use the harmonic representative.

Recall that acyclic resolution helps calculating cohomology. To be more precise , suppose we have an exact sequence of sheaves of the form:
$$0\to \mathscr{F}\to \mathscr{J}_0\to\mathscr{J}_1\to\cdot \to\mathscr{J}_r\to\cdots,$$ where $H^p(X,\mathscr{J}_r)=0$, $\forall p\geq 1$. (This is called an acyclic resolusion of $\mathscr{F}$). Then $H^*(X,\mathscr{F})\cong H^*(\Gamma(X,\mathscr{J}^*))$, that is $H^*(X,\mathscr{F})$ can be calculated by the cohomology of the chain complex
$$0\to \mathscr{J}_0(X)\to \mathscr{J}_1(X)\to \cdots \to \mathscr{J}_r(X)\to\cdots .$$ This is a basic fact of sheaf cohomology. In particular, we can consider the following two acyclic resolusion of constant sheaf $\mathbb{C}$ and structure sheaf $\mathscr{O}_X$:
$$0\to \mathbb{C}\to  \mathcal{A}_\mathbb{C}^0(X)\to \mathcal{A}_\mathbb{C}^1(X)\to \mathcal{A}_\mathbb{C}^2(X)\to \cdots;$$
$$0\to\mathscr{O}_X \to\mathcal{A}_\mathbb{C}^0(X)\to \mathcal{A}^{0,1}(X)\to \mathcal{A}^{0,2}(X)\to \cdots.$$ Here we use font $\mathcal{A}$ to indicate it's a sheaf. Using the basic fact above, we get
$$H^k(X,\mathbb{C})\cong H^k_{dR}(X,\mathbb{C}),\; H^k(X,\mathscr{O}_X)\cong H^{0,k}_{\bar{\partial}}(X).$$
The commutatice diagram indicates there is a chain map between $\mathscr{A}^\bullet_{\mathbb{C}}(X)\to \mathscr{A}^{0,\bullet}(X)$, where $\mathscr{A}^\bullet_{\mathbb{C}}(X)$ and $\mathscr{A}^{0,\bullet}$ are the chains
$$0\to  A_\mathbb{C}^0(X)\to A_\mathbb{C}^1(X)\to A_\mathbb{C}^2(X)\to \cdots;$$
$$0\to A_\mathbb{C}^0(X)\to A^{0,1}(X)\to A^{0,2}(X)\to \cdots$$respectively. Here we use font $A$ to indicate global sections of sheaf, i.e. differential forms. This chain map induces a natural map $H^k(X,\mathbb{C})\to H^{0,k}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)=H^k(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$.
Where do we use the harmonic representative? Acturally, if we want to explicitly write the map $H^k(X,\mathbb{C})\to H^k(X,\mathscr{O}_X)=H^{0,k}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)$, we have to go back to the closed chain of differential forms. The harmonic representative just serves this perpose.
Plus, if you take a look at the exercise 3.3.1, it claims that the lemma acturally "holds" without the kahler condition. This is because we only use the hodge decomposition at the last step to exsure $H^k(X,\mathbb{C})\to H^k(X,\mathscr{O}_X)=H^{0,k}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)$ is the projection of bidegree decomposition (at the level of cohomology groups). So if we make a compromise and only write the map at the level of differential forms, that is $A^k_{\mathbb{C}}(X)\to A^{0,k}(X)$, and induce a not that explicit map $H^k(X,\mathbb{C})\to H^k(X,\mathscr{O}_X)=H^{0,k}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)$, the lemma still holds.

I am not sure this is right. first in the complex $\mathscr{A}^{0,\bullet}$ you mean $0\to A_\mathbb{C}^{0}(X)\to A_\mathbb{C}^{0,1}(X)\to A_\mathbb{C}^{0,2}(X)\to \cdots$? How is $H^k(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ calculated by this complex, that complex is from Dolbeault cohomology.  What do you mean by long exact $0\to H^k(X,\mathbb{C})\to H^k(X,\mathscr{O}X)=H^{0,k}{\bar{\partial}}(X)\to 0,$? As you write it is short exact and how did you get $H^k(X,\mathscr{O}X)=H^{0,k}{\bar{\partial}}(X) $?

The answer is very unclear, the exactness of  $0\to H^k(X,\mathbb{C})\to H^k(X,\mathscr{O}X)=H^{0,k}{\bar{\partial}}(X)\to 0$, Also gives the isomorphism $H^k(X,\mathbb{C})\cong H^k(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$

I edited the answer.  The previous claimed short exact sequence is a stupid mistake. What I want to express is that the commutative diagram gives a chain map. @領域展開
